# Cannot load model from huggingface

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am working on Google Colab.
I load a model from huggingface.
In the first time, it can load model.
But in the second time, i get an error:

```
OSError: vinai/phobert-base does not appear to have a file named config.json. 
Checkout 'https://huggingface.co/vinai/phobert-base/None' for available files.type here
```

Could someone please help. Thank you!

I tried some solution on internet, But it can't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance you named your output folder the same as the model_id `vinai/phobert-base`? In this case if anything went wrong, the folder was created but there is not a valid model in the local folder. When loading the model `vinai/phobert-base` the next time, huggingface will prioritize this local folder, try to load it and fail. That would explain why it worked one time but not the following times.